# Why Select Case doesn't work in this code VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have to calculate "Costo" (Cost) by Select Case, but when I run the macro it just put 0 in Cost not the numbers I put in the macro. Something is missing and I don't know what. Cost (P5-P50) Tipo de Pase (O5-O50)

Excel Screenshot:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

```
Sub Ejercicio1()

Dim Estacionamiento As String
Dim Casillero As String
Dim TipoDePase As String
Dim Costo As Double
Dim contador As Double

contador = 5
Range("P5").Select

Do While contador <= 50

Select Case TipoDePase
    Case "Normal":
      Costo = 95200
    Case "Lounge":
      Costo = 280000
    Case "Lounge Premium":
      Costo = 392000

End Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
contador = contador + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you set `TipoDePase`?  You assign a value to `Costo` but don't do anything with it

Comment: It looks like you deleted and reposted.  Might either or both of the images from your original question be helpful here for context?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be helpful, I tried to upload the image in this post but I don't know if it worked.

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't telling VBA to look at your column, you have only named a variable and then you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your code isn't interreacting with the Workbook.  It doesn't get any variables from the workbook and it doesn't return anything to it.  This should work but I haven't tested it

```
Sub Ejercicio1()

Dim Estacionamiento As String
Dim Casillero As String
Dim TipoDePase As String
Dim Costo As Double
Dim contador As Double

contador = 5
Range("P5").Select

Do While contador <= 50
TipoDePase = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) 'Get value from column P
Select Case TipoDePase
    Case "Normal":
      ActiveCell = 95200
    Case "Lounge":
      ActiveCell = 280000
    Case "Lounge Premium":
      ActiveCell = 392000

End Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
contador = contador + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
Do While contador <= 50

Select Case TipoDePase
```

to this:

```
Do While contador <= 50

TipoDePase = Range("P" & contador).Value

Select Case TipoDePase
```

You can also delete these two lines, they have no function in your code:

```
Range("P5").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: What is the downvote for? My code works, and it avoids using `Select` (which is error-prone).